# Move inside list element position in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I'm trying to move a list element position when i click in another one

[image]

When i click thats what happen

[image]

I need the view to move up and stay like this without the user need to move it

[image]

```
        VStack{
            VStack{
                Button(action: {
                    self.iconeView.toggle()
                }) {
                    ZStack{
                        self.icone.renderingMode(.original)
                            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.4, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.2)
                    }
                }

            }//Photo
                .padding(.bottom, 54)
                .padding(.top, 42)

            List {

                VStack(alignment: .leading){
                    Text("Nome do remédio")
                }//Medicine Name
                .padding(.bottom, 10)

                VStack(alignment: .leading){
                    Text("Quantidade de remédio")
                }// Quantity
                    .padding(.bottom, 50)

                VStack(alignment: .leading){
                    Text("Horario Inicial")

                }//Start time

            }//List


        }//Screen
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have predefined number of elements it is more appropriate to use `ScrollView` instead of `List` here. So solution can be as follows (in pseudo code)

Update with full demo code. Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

[image: demo]

```
struct DemoMoveToTopView: View {
    @State private var showMedicalName = true
    @State private var showQuantaty = true

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
            if self.showMedicalName {
                VStack(alignment: .leading){
                    Text("Nome do remédio")
                }//Medicine Name
                    .frame(width: 300, height: 100)
                    .border(Color.red).background(Color.yellow)
                    .padding(.bottom, 10)
                    .transition(.opacity)
            }

            if self.showQuantaty {
                VStack(alignment: .leading){
                    Text("Quantidade de remédio")
                }// Quantity
                    .frame(width: 300, height: 100)
                    .border(Color.red).background(Color.yellow)
                    .padding(.bottom, 50)
                    .transition(.opacity)
            }

            VStack(alignment: .leading){
                Text("Horario Inicial")

            }//Start time
                .frame(width: 300, height: 100)
                    .border(Color.red).background(Color.white)
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.showMedicalName.toggle()      // << hide/show above
                    self.showQuantaty.toggle()         // << hide/show above

                    // .. do other needed
            }

            }.animation(.default)
        }//ScrollView
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but changing to ScrollView i still cant move a list element position to the top when the tapgesture is activated

Comment: @EduardoAirton, I believe something wrong happened during adapting of provided idea. See updated with full functional tested demo.